# Best way to store and query data in Apache Cassandra using Astyanax

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

i am kind of confused, don't know if i am doing it the right way. I have arbitrary json data coming via API, i have developed an algorithm that will transform the data to be able to write  it to fit cassandra columnar approach. i am a little confused, don't know if its the write way of writing data, because i have to use ad-hoc to query the data. here is an example:

```
{'sales': 'HP-Laptop', 'location': 'NY', 'working': 'Yes'}
String content = input.getString(0);
    JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(content);

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try{
        map = mapper.readValue(ob.get("content").toString(), new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();


     MutationBatch _mutation = _m;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        _mutation.withRow(EMP_CF, uuid.toString()).putColumn(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), null);
    }

    try {
       OperationResult<Void> result = _mutation.execute();
      } catch (ConnectionException e) {
        logger.error("failed to write data to C*", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("failed to write data to C*", e);
      }
      logger.debug("insert ok");
```

the ad-hoc logic is like this get all rows having this column: 'sales' where sales column have different value for each inserted record. i am using a storm topology and astyanax driver to do this.

Advices and recommendation is highly welcome.

Ebot.